# Binding variable, use variable in condition and returning variable, all within an if condition?

Tags: typescript

I often find myself binding a variable, using it to test a condition and then returning it if the condition is true/false.

```
const val = getAttribute(svgEl, "fill");
if (val) {
  return convertColorToTgml(val);
}
const ancestorVal = svgAncestorValue(svgEl, "fill");
if (ancestorVal) {
  return convertColorToTgml(ancestorVal);
}

return "#000000";
```

This is pretty hard to read to me. I quickly get confused. I would prefer to not have to bind each variable prior to the conditional statements. I would prefer something like:

Is there a briefer way to express this in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```js
...
const maybeAttribute = getAttribute(svgEl, "fill") || svgAncestorValue(svgEl, "fill")
return maybeAttribute
  ? convertColorToTgml(maybeAttribute)
  : "#000000"
```

Comment: Although this is shorter but the original is more clear (especially when another developer wants to change the code one year from now)

Comment: I mean, what's readable for someone might look more complicated to someone else, but I don't really see how this version could look unclear.
`maybeAttribute` -> try to get the `fill` attribute of `svgEl`, if it fails, try to do the same for its ancestor. If we managed to get a value, convert it, otherwise default to `#000000`

Comment: I used `more clear` it means your solution is `clear` but comparing to original post that one is `more clear`

Comment: Especially if the number of conditions are growing, then for sure using that much `||` make it less understandable